# Output path/filename for each file eith eslint

Tags: javascript, eslint, lint

Prettier outputs the name of each file it runs on to the stdout:

```
src/view/templates/alpha.js 4ms
src/view/templates/bravo.js 9ms
src/view/templates/charlie.js 2ms
src/view/templates/delta.js 6ms
```

Is there any way to have eslint do the same thing. It looks like the only way to tweak its output is with the `-o` flag, however this only redirects the output to a file. It offers a `--debug` flag, however this is very verbose.

Answer (score 1):

Well you could do `eslint - debug`, but that will output more than just the filenames.

Another option is to look at custom formatters that allow you to configure the output from eslint. If you just want to list filenames, then this simple formatter would do that for you, but then it won’t show you any errors

```
// only print filenames
module.exports = function(results) {
  return results
    .map(result => result.filePath).join('\n')
}
```

[eslint-formatter-summary-chart](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-formatter-summary-chart) will list the percentage of errors in each file, but only lists files with problems. The source code is pretty simple, so you should be able to hack it into listing files that don’t have errors

```
% eslint --format summary-chart src
 
==== Files ====
bar.js : ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇  33.33%
foo.js : ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇  66.67%
 
 
==== Rules ====
constructor-super     : ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇  16.67%
no-cond-assign        : ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇  16.67%
no-constant-condition : ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇  16.67%
no-debugger           : ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇  16.67%
no-unused-vars        : ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇  33.33%
```